# PHP RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: php

Помогите ошибку найти... 
Заголовок отправляемый серверу:

```
POST /asist/rp_d.php HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 39

trertertektj;rtejrlktertlerterterterete
```

Содержимое rp_d.php

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo ">>>$postdata<<< \r\n >>>$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA<<<";
```

Ответ от сервера:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2013 08:27:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
Content-Length: 18
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

>>><<<
>>><<<
```

Содержимое .htaccess

```
php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data On
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting -1
```

Comment: А ``#13#10`` [работает](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)?  

    Возврат каретки: CR \r 0x0D 13 #13
    Подача строки:   LF \n 0x0A 10 #10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема найдена, и в публикации ее небыло...
В делфе строки выглядели как

```
Head:='POST http://myhost/asist/rp_d.php HTTP/1.0'#10#13+{продолжение запроса}
```

а нужно было

```
Head:='POST http://myhost/asist/rp_d.php HTTP/1.0'#10+{продолжение запроса}
```

Хотя непонятно куда пропадает перевод строки.... вроде как по спецификации должно быть \r\n что в паскалях \r - #10 \n - #13... если кто пояснит - буду благодарен.